# why is VAE reconstruction loss equal to MSE loss

Tags: loss-functions, autoencoders, mse, variational-bayes

At which situations does reconstruction loss of VAE equals MSE loss between input and reconstructed output?

Other answers where not complete!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VAE models a distribution

$$P(x) = \int P(x|z)P(z) dz$$

When the output is continuous valued, then a common parameterization of $P(x|z)$ is as $$\mathcal{N}(\mu = f(z;\theta), \sigma^2)$$

Recall that a VAE is trained by maximizing the variational lower bound, which can be broken down into two terms:

$$E_{z \sim q}[\log P(x|z)] - \text{KL}(q(z)||p(z))$$

But then the first term is merely the log of the gaussian density, which is (up to some scaling and constants) $(x-\mu)^2$. Hence MSE.

Comment: $P(x|z)$ in VAE should be some kind of neural net. Regard neural nets as Gaussians?

Comment: @JPZhang sorry - can't tell exactly what you're asking, it might be best to open a new question.

Comment: Why $p(x|z)$ is a Gaussian? In practice, it should a trained neural network, sometimes called `decoder`. @shimao

Comment: it's unclear what it would even mean for $p(x|z)$ to *be* a neural network, since neural networks are not distributions. Instead, you can see that as I've written it above, $p(x|z)$ is a normal distribution whose mean is specified by the decoder $f(z; \theta)$.

Comment: He means that the mean and variance of $P(x | z)$ is specified by a NN

Comment: Just to add to this, I think it's important to note that the log of Gaussian density is not the MSE, but the negative MSE. Therefore, the reconstruction term is (up to some scaling and constants as the answer states), the negative MSE, which we want to maximize. Equivalently, you usually end up minimizing the negative log density (minimizing negative log-likelihood), so you will minimize the MSE.